# a sharp challenge to/for

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference

While reading "the American Pageant" by Thomas A. Bailey, I came across the following text.

> A sharp challenge **to** Puritan orthodoxy came from Anne Hutchinson. She
>   was an exceptionally intelligent, strong-willed, and talkative woman,
>   ultimately the mother of fourteen children.

I have checked this similar thread https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134214/a-challenge-to-x-vs-a-challenge-for-x?rq=1  for more than 10 times.

> "Challenges for food security" sounds like "food security" is some
>   sort of entity or organization that is facing challenges......

I am still confused with the difference between "challenge to" and "challenge for". I would be eager to know whether I can use "for" instead of "to" in the text (A sharp challenge **for** Puritan orthodoxy).

Answer (score 1):

**A sharp challenge to Puritan orthodoxy came from Anne Hutchinson.**

> **to** preposition (**RECEIVING**)[Link C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/to) Therefore we could write

**Puritan orthodoxy received a sharp challenge from Anne Hutchinson.**

> **For**; **because** of or as a result of something:[Link to C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for)

A sharp challenge **for** Puritan orthodoxy **cannot be used** because the meaning would be incorrect. When we substitute **because of** for **For** the sentence becomes

**A sharp challenge because of Puritan orthodoxy**

Using your example "**Challenges for food security** >> we can substitute **because of** for **For** which becomes

**Challenges because of food security**"

> I don't eat meat for various reasons. >>I don't eat meat because of various reasons.[Link C.E.D](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for)

Answer (score 1):

A sharp challenge to Puritan orthodoxy came from X, is from the outside, where X is seen as a whole.

A sharp challenge for Puritan orthodoxy was X, suggests the challenge is being view by those who espouse Puritan orthodoxy.

A challenge **to** the team = as a unit or whole
A challenge for the team = the inside of the team, looked at from the inside, its members

Answer (score 1):

> A sharp challenge **to** Puritan orthodoxy came from Anne Hutchinson

means that Anne Hutchinson challenged Puritan orthodoxy (she fought/opposed it). "Of" or "against" could also work there.

If something is a challenge **for** somebody, it means they find it challenging/difficult.